# how do i resolve this error: TypeError: 'type' object is not subscriptable"

Tags: python, abstract-data-type

am creating a shooter game and i observed something. everything in my code was working well until i created a dictionary and tried to access it through its key in a function but instead i got this error: TypeError: 'type' object is not subscriptable.
below is where i declared the dictionary, called it in a class, and where i created an instance of it from a class respectively

```
grenade_img = pygame.image.load("img/icons/grenade.png").convert_alpha()
# pick up boxes
health_box_img = pygame.image.load("img/icons/health_box.png").convert_alpha()
ammo_box_img = pygame.image.load("img/icons/ammo_box.png").convert_alpha()
grenade_box_img = pygame.image.load("img/icons/grenade_box.png").convert_alpha()
# name_dt = type(name)
item_boxes = {
    "health": health_box_img,
    "ammo": ammo_box_img,
    "grenade": grenade_img,
}
```

````
class ItemBox(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self, item_type, x, y):
        pygame.sprite.Sprite.__init__(self)
        self.item_type = item_type
        self.image = item_boxes[self.item_type]
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect()
        self.rect.midtop = (x + TILE_SIZE // 2, y + (TILE_SIZE - self.image.get_height()))


# create item boxes
item_box = ItemBox["health", 100, 300]
item_box_group.add(item_box)
item_box = ItemBox["ammo", 400, 300]
item_box_group.add(item_box)
item_box = ItemBox["grenade", 500, 300]
item_box_group.add(item_box)```
````

please can anyone show me what else to do to get result

Comment: I think you are trying to use a class as a dic. You shouldn't do `ItemBox[]`, but instead `ItemBox()` to initialize ...also where does `item_box_group` come from? There are many other comments but a general one is that in its current form (the question), it is hard to understand which line of code triggers the error. Can you be more specific?

Answer (score 0):

The error is because you use square brackets `[]` instead of normal brackets `()`  creating `ItemBox` objects. You can replace them and everything should work fine. The code from 2nd frame is

```
item_box = ItemBox("health", 100, 300)
item_box_group.add(item_box)
item_box = ItemBox("ammo", 400, 300)
item_box_group.add(item_box)
item_box = ItemBox("grenade", 500, 300)
item_box_group.add(item_box)
```

after replacing.

Comment: thanks a million. how did i not see that in the first place? am really grateful. it worked

Comment: You're welcome! I'd appreciate if you mark my response as the correct one :)

Comment: how do i do that?

Comment: I don't know. I haven't asked any question yet.